# Google Analytics export setup to Bigquery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I was able to setup the GA360 to bigquery and I also got an email that export is complete. But I dont see anything when I click on the dataset. Will it take time for the tables to show up or do I need to create tables once I setup the dataset in bigquery?

Answer (score 0):

If you successfully connected GA360, you don't need to anything else additional for it to work. Make sure you're using the correct account for the Big Query project.
It will take time for the day-of data to show up as well as a few days for the 13 months of data to show up.